# Why am I not getting the desired output of my C program?

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

```
//Aim of this program is to print a hash pyramid

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height, spaces, hash;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the height of the wall:\n");  // Prompt the user for the height
        height = get_int();
    }
    while(height<0 || height>23);

    for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        for (spaces= height-i; spaces>1; spaces--)
        {
            printf(" ");                //print spaces
            for (hash= 0; hash<=height+1; hash++)
            {
                printf("#");                //print hashes
            }
            printf("\n");                    //move to the next line
        }
    }
}
```

This is a program to print a pyramid of hashes.
I am doing this as a part of my CS50x course on edx, so I have included the CS50 library.Now, regarding the program, I know that I've messed up something in the third 'for loop', but I don't know what it is.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: What is `h` in `while(h<0 || h>23);`?

Comment: What is the expected output if a user inputs for instance the number 3?

Comment: Your third for loop should be after, not inside, the second for loop.

Comment: My bad! h and height are the same

Comment: @Adit always post real code

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That isn't working. I'm not getting a proper pyramid

Comment: @Jabberwocky What do you mean?

Comment: That's curious; you've accepted an answer which does what I said you should do, so unless your loop limits were off, what I suggested was what you found necessary and acceptable.

Comment: @Adit read this [mcve]

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, what I thought you suggested was to just separate the two for loops, but then I read the answer below, and it turns out that my initial code was wrong in the first place, my mistake

Comment: @Jabberwocky Well, you see, I am new to this site, I read that now. Will keep in mind :)

Comment: @Adit To ensure that the posted code can be compiled, I changed `h` to `height` in accordance with your comment

Comment: @4386427 Yeah, no problem, I was going to do that anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems in your code

1) The loop that prints `#` shall **not** be inside the loop printing spaces

2) The loop that prints `#` have incorrect stop condition

3) Seems you have messed up `h` and `height`. I'll just assume that they should be the same all over

Try like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int h, spaces, hash;

    h = 5;  // Fixed input to simplify code example

    for (int i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        for (spaces= h-i; spaces>1; spaces--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (hash= 0; hash<=2*i; hash++)  // Notice: <= 2*i
        {
          printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    #
   ###
  #####
 #######
#########
```

Comment: I don't really understand what the 2*i means...What's it?

Comment: `2*i` (together with use of `<=`) is the number of `#` to print on the current line. An alternative way of writing that line would be: `for (hash= 0; hash < (2*i + 1); hash++)`

Comment: Ohh Okay! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Do it with 1 loop.
**You do not need 3 loops!**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int height;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter the height of the wall:\n");  // Prompt the user for the height
        scanf("%d", &height);
    }
    while(height<0 || height>23);

    for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d: %*.*s\n", i+1, height+i, 2*i+1, "########################################");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample Output with Height 6:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4284KB
1:      #
2:     ###
3:    #####
4:   #######
5:  #########
6: ###########
```

Comment: Are you deliberatly setting a trap?

Answer (score 1):

following code should work for you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
    {
        int i, height, spaces, hash;
        do
        {
        printf("Enter the height of the wall:\n");   
                                    // Prompt the user for the height
        scanf("%d", &height);// = get_int();
        }
        while(height<0 || height >= 23);

  for ( i=0; i<height; i++)
  {
    for (spaces= height - i; spaces>1; spaces--)
    {
        printf(" ");                //print spaces
    }
    for (hash= 0; hash<=i; hash++)
    {
        printf("# ");                //print hashes
    }
    printf("\n");                    //move to the next line

   // }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple you are taking the variable input in Variable called "**height**", inside the for loop you have used a variable h which is not initialized.
The Third **for loop** would be outside the Second for Loop

This would be your loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<h; i++)
{
    for (spaces= h-i; spaces>1; spaces--)
    {
        printf(" ");  
    }

    for (hash= 0; hash<=h+1; hash++)
    {
        printf("#");                //print hashes
    }
    printf("\n");                    //move to the next line
    }
}
```